# Spring social custom OAuth2Version

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-social

I tried to interface a RESTfull web service and after some research I found the  [spring-social project](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#section_implementing) that give a nice way to make an API binding to REST resource with different security mechanism like OAuth1a/2 out of the box.

My problem is that the Web service I try to interface doesn't match all aspect of OAuth2 in spring social when calling secure rest endpoint, especially the access token transmission for each call.

Spring Social give 4 OAuth2 version specification:

- BEARER : with header value of "Bearer "
- BEARER_DRAFT_2 : with header value of "Oauth2 "
- DRAFT_10 : with header value of "Oauth "
- DRAFT_8 : with header value of "Token token="""

and 3 token strategies

- AUTHORIZATION_HEADER : Indicates that the access token should be carried in the Authorization header as an OAuth2 Bearer token
- ACCESS_TOKEN_PARAMETER : Indicates that the access token should be carried as a query parameter named "access_token"
- OAUTH_TOKEN_PARAMETER : Indicates that the access token should be carried as a query parameter named "oauth_token".

So my problem is the web service handle the access token differently like this:

- By parameter with `http://base_api_path/?token=<accessToken>`

Or

- With a custom header `X-<Vendor>-Token: <token>`

So how can I override the spring social default Oauth2 mechanism?

I hope my question is clear enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [spring-social-linkedin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-linkedin) project they do something like you want, you might want to take a look to the **OAuth2TokenParameterRequestInterceptor** method of this [**class**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-linkedin/blob/master/spring-social-linkedin/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/linkedin/api/impl/LinkedInTemplate.java)